# TypeScript classes : constructor and method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to avoid double declaration in my Typescript classes.

Before I was writing my classes like that :

```
module ModuleName {
    export class ClassName {
        public method: () => void;

        constructor(
            private dependency: any ) {
            this.method = () => {
                dependency.someUse();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

But the declaration of the type of the method (here `public method: () => void;`) looks useless, especially when you already have an interface which declare it. So I wanted to write :

```
module ModuleName {
    export class ClassName {
        constructor(
            private dependency: any ) { }

        public method = () => {
            this.dependency.someUse();
        };

    }
}
```

Note : To avoid warnings `variable XXX used before declaration`, we have to put the methods after the constructor.

But now if we use our methods in the constructor, we again get the warnings on this methods :

```
module ModuleName {
    export class ClassName {
        constructor(
            private dependency: any ) {
            this.method(); // warning here
        }

        public method = () => {
            this.dependency.someUse();
        };

    }
}
```

So, my question is : **How should we write our classes properly ?**

*Note : As typescript compiler corrects the declaration's order, that's not a big deal, I just want to know if it's possible to write classes without double declarations and warnings.*

Comment: What's going on with "warning here" in that last example? There's no error when I paste that code into the Playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think it is a bad idea to remove this warning because it can be very usefull in some cases.

But I found how to solve my problem :
If we **move the constructor to the end of the class**, we have no more warnings :

```
module ModuleName {
    export class ClassName {

        public method = () => {
            this.dependency.someUse();
        };

        constructor(
            private dependency: any ) {
            this.method();
        }

    }
}
```

If we look at the generated JS that easier to understand what is happening : the constructor's parameters are still placed at the start of the generated function :

```
var ModuleName;
(function (ModuleName) {
    var ClassName = (function () {
        function ClassName(dependency) {
            var _this = this;
            this.dependency = dependency;
            this.method = function () {
                _this.dependency.someUse();
            };
            this.method();
        }
        return ClassName;
    })();
    ModuleName.ClassName = ClassName;
})(ModuleName || (ModuleName = {}));
```

Comment: That's not good. The issue should be reported to TSLint if it already hasn't been.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a error from TSLint. Are you by any change using WebEssentials?

You might want to disable this rule as from what you are saying it looks buggy. WebEssentials loads the `tslint.json` from your user home directory (`%userprofile%`). You should be able to find a tslint.json file there. This is the place where you can enable/disable rules.

It sounds like there is a bug in the following rule

> `no-use-before-declare` disallows usage of variables before their declaration`

You can disable this rule by adding (or changing) the configuration with this:

```
"no-use-before-declare": false
```

More info about tslint and its rules can be found here: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/

Answer (score -2):

Your error `variable XXX used before declaration` is caused because declaring your class methods as class properties.

Instead of declaring your method like this:

```
public method = () => {
```

Declare it like this:

```
public method() {
```

So your class would look like this:

```
module ModuleName {
    export class ClassName {
        constructor(private dependency: any ) { }

        public method() {
            this.dependency.someUse();
        }
    }
}
```